# Show enqueued CSS and Script in custom header

Tags: css, javascript

This should be very simple ! We have enqueued CSS and scripts in our theme, they are registered and display properly when using the wp_head method.

I have searched and searched but cannot find an answer - how do you display the enqueued CSS and scripts only ? Essentially like wp_title but with the styles and scripts.

Comment: And why you don’t want to use wp_head?

Comment: It's a dynamically generated header so the meta tags etc use info from a different table. Hence needing the css and script only from WordPress so that plugins don't break on that page.

Comment: I see. I’ll post my answer later today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So all we need to do is to check, what exactly WP is doing during `wp_head` and mimic that behavior...

In `wp-includes/default-filters.php` (line 244) you can find:

```
add_action( 'wp_head',             '_wp_render_title_tag',            1     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_enqueue_scripts',              1     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_resource_hints',               2     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links',                      2     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'feed_links_extra',                3     );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'rsd_link'                               );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wlwmanifest_link'                       );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'locale_stylesheet'                      );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'noindex',                          1    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'print_emoji_detection_script',     7    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_styles',                  8    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_print_head_scripts',            9    );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_generator'                           );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'rel_canonical'                          );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_shortlink_wp_head',            10, 0 );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_custom_css_cb',                101   );
add_action( 'wp_head',             'wp_site_icon',                    99    );
```

One way would be to remove all redundant actions and use `wp_head` in custom header.

Another solution is calling the functions manually in there. So in your custom header you can do this:

```
<?php
    wp_enqueue_scripts();
    wp_print_styles();
    wp_print_head_scripts();
?>
```

and it should be enough.

Comment: Pefect - just what I was looking for !